# проверка раскладки на python

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, поиск-программ, проверка-орфографии

хочу сделать скрипт по типу:
вводишь текст -> прога проверяет, правильная ли раскладка -> если нет, то пишет исправленный вариант. типа как в поисковиках. например:

`юзер: привет`
`прога:` 
`юзер: ghbdtn`
`прога: привет`

есть ли для этого какие-то библиотеки или сервисы? заранее спасибо

Comment: для этого уже есть готовые программы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может есть и готовые варианты, но могу предложить примерный путь, куда можно двигаться самому, это не сложно. Берём готовую подборку частот двухбуквенных сочетаний и проверяем, насколько введённое слово получается "естественным" в той раскладке, в которой оно введено:

```
import pandas as pd

def is_good(word, freq):
    word = word.lower()
    metric = [freq.get(a+b, 0) for a, b in zip(word, word[1:]) if a.isalpha() and b.isalpha()]
    return round(sum(metric) / len(metric), 2), word

# Частотность двухбуквенных сочетаний
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RRf5NIF1d0k9VonrByQXfUGu3tO41rYFu6gmg75IlSg/edit#gid=0'
df = pd.read_html(url, index_col=0, encoding='UTF-8')[0]
df = df.iloc[:,:2]
df.to_csv('ru_freq_2.csv', index=False)
df['C'] = df['B'] * len(df['B']) / df['B'].sum()
d = dict(df[['A','C']].values)

print(is_good('Привет!', d))
print(is_good('руддщ!', d)) # hello!
print(is_good('финтифлюшка', d))
print(is_good('вуглускр', d))
print(is_good('кандибобер', d))
print(is_good('Владимир', d))
print(is_good('Какое-то длинное длинное предложение из нормальных слов', d))
```

Вывод:

```
(1.04, 'привет!')
(0.14, 'руддщ!')
(0.32, 'финтифлюшка')
(0.13, 'вуглускр')
(0.63, 'кандибобер')
(0.42, 'владимир')
(1.0, 'какое-то длинное длинное предложение из нормальных слов')
```

Как можно видеть, чем "натуральнее" слово, тем у него больше метрика получается. Что ещё нужно сделать:

- сделать функцию транслитерации в другую раскладку
- взять английский частотный словарь, чтобы считать "натуральность" английских слов
- считать четыре варианта метрики: (два варианта раскладки) * (частоты английские, частоты русские)
- у какого варианта из четырёх будет больше всего метрика, ту раскладку и оставляем как правильную

Примерно вот так. Ну или если сразу разобраться, какая из раскладок русская, а какая английская, то можно только две метрики считать - русскую для русской раскладки, английскую для английской, какая больше - та и правильная.

Вообще надо будет потом доработать и сделать прямо пакет питоновский для этого дела, наверное. :)

**UPDATE:** Дописал полный код. Вроде работает, хотя местами надо подкручивать под сложные случаи, видимо. Немного пришлось отклониться от первоначального плана. В частности пришлось ввести порог разности метрики, после которого можно переключаться. Иначе сомнительные слова вроде "вуглускр" норовят переключиться на английскую раскладку почём зря.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

def calc_text_naturality(text, freq):
    save_text = text
    text = text.lower()
    metric = [freq.get(a+b, 0.2) for a, b in zip(text, text[1:]) if a.isalpha() and b.isalpha()]
    return ((sum(metric) / len(metric)) ** 0.5, save_text)

def translate_text(text, dict_):
    return ''.join(dict_.get(x, x) for x in text)

def find_lang(text, threshold = 0.333):
    trans_eng = translate_text(text, rus2eng)
    trans_rus = translate_text(text, eng2rus)
    scores = (calc_text_naturality(text, freq_eng),
              calc_text_naturality(text, freq_rus),
              calc_text_naturality(trans_eng, freq_eng),
              calc_text_naturality(trans_eng, freq_rus),
              calc_text_naturality(trans_rus, freq_eng),
              calc_text_naturality(trans_rus, freq_rus))
    #print(scores)
    max_score = max(scores)
    orig_score = max(scores[:2])
    return max_score[1] if(max_score[0] - threshold > orig_score[0]) else text

rus_key = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ"
eng_key = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP[]ASDFGHJKL;'ZXCVBNM,."
rus2eng = dict(zip(rus_key, eng_key))
eng2rus = dict(zip(eng_key, rus_key))

# русские биграммы
url_ru = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RRf5NIF1d0k9VonrByQXfUGu3tO41rYFu6gmg75IlSg/edit#gid=0'
df = pd.read_html(url_ru, index_col=0, encoding='UTF-8')[0]
df = df.iloc[:,:2]
df['C'] = df['B'] * len(df['B']) / df['B'].sum()
df.to_csv('ru_freq_2.csv', index=False)
freq_rus = dict(df[['A','C']].values)

# английские биграммы
url_en = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lydell/c439049abac2c9226e53/raw/4cfe39fd90d6ad25c4e683b6371009f574e1177f/bigrams.json'
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(requests.get(url_en).text), columns=['A','B'])
#print(df.shape)
df = df.sort_values('B', ascending=False)[:100]
df['C'] = df['B'] * len(df['B']) / df['B'].sum()
df.to_csv('ru_freq_2.csv', index=False)
freq_eng = dict(df[['A','C']].values)

corpus = [
    'Привет!',
    'ты кто такой вообще',
    'руддщ!', # hello
    'финтифлюшка',
    'вуглускр',
    'кандибобер',
    'Владимир',
    'Какое-то длинное длинное предложение из нормальных слов',
    'hello',
    'ghbdtn', # привет
    'цудсщьу ещ Ьщысщц', # welcome to Moscow
    'тыщ тыщ тыдыщ',
    'omg',
    'lorem ipsum',
    'хрен знает что такое'
]
for text in corpus:
    print(f'{text} -> {find_lang(text)}')
```

Вывод:

```
Привет! -> Привет!
ты кто такой вообще -> ты кто такой вообще
руддщ! -> hello!
финтифлюшка -> финтифлюшка
вуглускр -> вуглускр
кандибобер -> кандибобер
Владимир -> Владимир
Какое-то длинное длинное предложение из нормальных слов -> Какое-то длинное длинное предложение из нормальных слов
hello -> hello
ghbdtn -> привет
цудсщьу ещ Ьщысщц -> welcome to Moscow
тыщ тыщ тыдыщ -> тыщ тыщ тыдыщ
omg -> omg
lorem ipsum -> lorem ipsum
хрен знает что такое -> хрен знает что такое
```

Comment: круто, спасибо!

Comment: @gneg Дописал полный код, если что.

Comment: Может в модуль запаковать? Вы реально - Эльф безбашенный, в хорошем смысле=)

Comment: @Dmitry Надо разобраться, как это делать ещё. Наверняка тут где-то написано на сайте в ответах, надо поискать )